# Differentiate between feature detectors and descriptors

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-preprocessing

I was solving my Image Processing - Features descriptors when I came across this problem. I could not understand the difference between image detectors and descriotors

I tried googling but could not get any clear differences.

Comment: See here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24346/what-is-the-difference-between-feature-detectors-and-feature-descriptors . If you do not understand this, ask specific question at that website. If its related to programming ask here at SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A feature detector merely finds features (of some desired kind) in an image. There is little that you can do with just a list of where features were found.

A feature descriptor characterizes a feature by geometric (size, orientation, shape, ...) or radiometric quantities (lightness, saturation variance, local structure tensor...): it describes the feature by means of a list of numerical properties. Descriptors allow to match features from different sources, for example for tasks such as registration.